# OpenVpn dosen't work with pppoe connection

Tags: openvpn, pppoe

When I want to connect to my `openvpn` It worked fine and I have ping form `google` but when connect with pppoe connection and then set up my `openvpn` it doesn't work I think maybe because pppoe is kind of vpn two vpn in same time cause problem is this true?